# Count and mark open and closed tags from a textbox

Tags: html, tags

I`ll try to explain what i need as simply as i can.

I have a text area in which i paste some text that contains html tags.
The tags are between some random  text and i need to find if there are any broken tags.
For now a i have the code to count how many opening and closing divs i have. But lets say i have 10 opening divs and 9 closing divs. I need to find where exactly inside the text area is that missing closing div. The closing div is not actually missing , but it can be just written badly , for example like this "".

I hope this is clear enough.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Stacks.

Whenever you come across an opening tag, push it into the stack.

Whenever you come across a closing tag, check if the top of stack is the same as the closing tag you have got. 
If yes, then pop out the top element of the stack.
If No, then there lies your problem.

Note : You need to take the cases such as `<img ... /> , < br />` as special cases and just ignore these kinds of tags.